# Content overflowing off page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I am making my website when I created a fixed navigation bar on the left side of my page with the width of 250px and then I have a div to the right of it being my page content, I have set the width of that to 100% and inside that I have a col-lg-12 and the content is leaking off the page, I was wondering if anyone knew a solution to this so that the content box is only the width of the remaining width of the page instead of being always 100% of the page width, If you need the code I can upload it to pastebin or something like that. But I am putting just some lil tid bits of the code here. And if any more info is needed just comment.

```css
.navigationWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.contentWrapper {
    left: 255px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navigationWrapper">
    <div class="navIcon">
        <span>ICON</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-12 test">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post a fiddle if possible mate and why don't you just use boostrap's grid formation for whole thing. Make a column for navIcon part and in other column your other data.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Why you can not use bootstrap class in left sidebar?

Comment: Here I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quL1g5o0/

Comment: Also @Jainam I do not like the look of how bootstrap scales it as you make the page smaller I dont think that belongs in a sidebar I think it only looks good for the page content

Comment: I can use bootstrap class in left sidebar you can see my demo. and it's easy way to use  responsive for your whole site

Answer (score 0):

you can use Flexbox to do this:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Marouen/mt387m1t/). There are some height properties, which should be fixed.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.navigationwrapper {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
.contentWrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

with flex: 1 0 auto you can grantee that the element will grow and take the rest of the space left.

and this is your updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Marouen/n9v4Ly7e/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc()` in your CSS because the width of your container is not 100% but 100% - `menu width`

It makes something like : `width: calc(100% - 255px);` because you are starting your container from 255px left.

[updated js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quL1g5o0/2/)

PS : i also added `background-color:black;` to your `.navNav{}` so the background works even if the viewport is smaller than the size of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the `width: 100%;` you have applied to the `.contentWrapper` referances the width of it's parent (in this case the body) and not remaining space. You can use `width: calc(100% - 255px);` (see updated example below) to fix the issue. Flex-box is also reasonable solution, but this is what was causing the issue.

```css
.navigationWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.contentWrapper {
    left: 255px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 255px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navigationWrapper">
    <div class="navIcon">
        <span>ICON</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-12 test">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```